# Différence entre un texte narratif et un texte descriptif

Tags: grammaire, narration

Sur un site d'exercices de français, le texte suivant :

> Au-dessus de ce troisième étage étaient un grenier à étendre le linge et deux mansardes où couchaient un garçon de peine, nommé Christophe, et la grosse Sylvie, la cuisinière. Outre les sept pensionnaires internes, madame Vauquer avait, bon an, mal an, huit étudiants en Droit ou en Médecine, et deux ou trois habitués qui demeuraient dans le quartier, abonnés tous pour le dîner seulement. La salle contenait à dîner dix-huit personnes et pouvait en admettre une vingtaine ; mais le matin, il ne s'y trouvait que sept locataires dont la réunion offrait pendant le déjeuner l'aspect d'un repas de famille. Chacun descendait en pantoufles, se permettait des observations confidentielles sur la mise ou sur l'air des externes, et sur les événements de la soirée précédente, en s'exprimant avec la confiance de l'intimité.

(Honoré de Balzac, Le Père Goriot)

est considéré comme un texte descriptif. Je comprends parfaitement pourquoi il l'est, cependant, j'aimerais savoir s'il peut aussi être considéré comme un texte narratif et sinon, pourquoi ?

D'un autre côté, ce texte est classé comme narratif :

> Il était une fois un gentilhomme qui épousa en secondes noces une
> femme, la plus hautaine et la plus fière qu'on eût jamais vue. Elle
> avait deux filles de son humeur, et qui lui ressemblaient en toutes
> choses. Le mari avait de son côté une jeune fille, mais d'une douceur
> et d'une bonté sans exemple ; elle tenait cela de sa mère, qui était
> la meilleure personne du monde.

(Charles Perrault, "Cendrillon")

Je comprends qu'il soit narratif car l'on constate que les personnages sont clairement définis. Le narrateur les connaît parfaitement et parle à la troisième personne du singulier : il s'agit d'un narrateur omniscient. Cependant, j'aurais tendance à également dire que c'est un texte descriptif.

Dans le cas général comment reconnaître lorsqu'un texte est descriptif, narratif ou les deux si c'est possible ?

Answer (score 1):

Voici une définition concise du terme « narratif » ([définition](https://interlettre.com/bac/687-le-texte-narratif-definition-caracteristiques-et-exemples)).

> On parle de narration lorsqu’un texte fait le récit d’événements, réels ou fictifs, qui impliquent des faits, des personnages, des lieux, un déroulement, et un narrateur.

Selon cette définition donc, les deux textes sont narratifs.

[Définition](https://www.languefr.net/2018/11/les-caracteristiques-du-texte-descriptif.html) du texte descriptif.

> Dans un texte descriptif, l'auteur indique comment est un objet, un paysage, un lieu, une atmosphère, un être, une action, un évènement, une situation, un concept, une procédure, un processus, un fonctionnement.

D'apprès cette définition, les deux textes sont descriptifs. Il est difficile cependant de concevoir un texte narratif qui soit uniquement narratif alors que la caractérisation d'un texte purement descriptif est sans problème. Il existe des problèmes d'identification précise des deux et on parle de cette question dans cet [article-ci](https://www.unige.ch/lettres/framo/enseignements/methodes/description/deintegr.html) (
Méthodes et problèmes — La description — Laurent Jenny, © 2004 Dpt de Français moderne – Université de Genève).

> Pour y voir plus clair, il nous faut passer par une délimitation de la description. Apparemment la définition de la description est simple. Un récit se compose deux types représentations: des représentations d'actions et d'événements d'une part, et d'autre part des représentations d'objets, de lieux, de personnages. Ce sont ces dernières que nous appelons des descriptions.
>
> Cette distinction semble très claire. Mais, dans la pratique, elle est un peu plus difficile à cerner. En effet, nous voyons clairement où commence une représentation d'action: dès qu'apparaît un verbe d'action qui s'applique à un agent animé. Mais il est peut-être moins évident de définir où commence une description. Réfléchissons sur un exemple inspiré de Frontières du récit de Gérard Genette. Soient ces deux énoncés:
>
> - La maison était blanche avec un toit d'ardoise et des volets verts
> - L'homme s'approcha de la table et prit un couteau.
>
> Le premier énoncé est clairement descriptif. Il ne comporte aucune représentation d'action; en revanche, il évoque plusieurs objets (maison, toit, volets) et les qualifie par des adjectifs. Il ne fait pas de doute que le second est narratif puisqu'il comporte deux verbes d'action qui s'appliquent à un sujet animé, mais est-il purement narratif? À y regarder de plus près, il comporte la désignation de trois substantifs (homme, table, couteau) qu'on peut déjà considérer comme des amorces de description d'une scène. La simple nomination d'être animés ou inanimés a une valeur descriptive, et d'autant plus que terme est plus spécifique: "cabriolet" est plus descriptif que "voiture". De même pour les verbes d'action: "saisir" est plus descriptif que "prendre".

> Donc, on peut imaginer une description pure, où il ne se passerait absolument rien, mais on peut difficilement concevoir une narration pure, où absolument rien ne serait décrit. De ce point de vue, la description semble bien avoir une position dominante dans le discours littéraire. Cependant, dans la réalité des œuvres littéraires, c'est l'inverse: on ne rencontre quasiment pas de pures descriptions, elles apparaissent presque toujours dans la dépendance d'un récit.

Answer (score 1):

Le premier extrait est assez purement descriptif. Il ne raconte pas ce qui s'est passé à tel ou tel moment mais décrit simplement un lieu en donnant des informations sur celui-ci sans qu'il y ait d'enchaînement chronologique entre elles.

Le deuxième extrait commence par une phrase archétypement narrative « **il était une fois...** » Il ne fait pas de doute qu'on va raconter une histoire. Ensuite, les deuxième et troisième phrases décrivent les personnages du récit. Isolées du contexte, elles pourrait donc être considérées comme descriptives mais la suite revient clairement dans le domaine de la narration :

> Les noces ne furent pas plus tôt faites que la belle-mère fit éclater sa mauvaise humeur : elle ne put souffrir les bonnes qualités de cette jeune enfant, qui rendaient ses filles encore plus haïssables.

On y narre des faits qui s'enchaînent les uns aux autres.